# Call a function on closing Jasny Off canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasny-bootstrap

I implemented jasny bootstrap in one of my webpages for Offcanvas push menu. It opens whenever i click on the button. But it closes when either I click on button again or anywhere outside(body) of Jasny Off-canvas .

How do i call a function whenever jasny off-canvas is closed.
I searched for events but only body class is appended to (.canvas-slid) when canvas opens and this class gets removed on closing.

Jasny canvas i implemented is : http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read [documentation](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas) again.

You can try :

```
$('#myMenu').on('hidden.bs.offcanvas', function (e) {
     ...
});
```

Comment: how do fix it? I need to close the offcanvas after clic in any <li> or <a>